# How does one determine if an integer is octal or decimal when it is not entered as a string?

Tags: java

I have a code that converts decimals to binary, but while testing it I noticed that if an octal was entered it would output the "wrong" result.

I was wondering if there is any way to exclude octals if they are entered as the integer input when the function is called. So if 0123 is used as the parameter instead of 123, the method would run using 123 as the input or return null for an invalid input. **The method must take an int as the input.**

The wrapper method checks if the decimal is less than 0 and the helper recursively finds the binary string. Finally, the wrapper removes leading 0s and outputs a binary string.

```
    public static String decimalToBinary(int decimal) {
    if (decimal < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    String result = xDecimalToBinary(decimal);
    /*
     * the following section checks for a string of 0s and removes all of them,
     * leaving the last one if the string is all 0s
     */
    if (result.charAt(0) == '0') {
        result.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
    }
    return "0b" + result;
    }

    private static String xDecimalToBinary(int decimal) {
    if (decimal == 0 || decimal == 1) {
        return "" + decimal;
    }
    /*
     * builds binary string right to left taking the recursion of decimalToBin of
     * decimal / 2 on the left and the remainder of decimal / 2 (%2) on the right
     */
    else {
        return "" + xDecimalToBinary(decimal / 2) + decimal % 2;
    }
    }
```

Note: This is for a class, but this specific functionality is not a part of the assignment, rather it stems from my curiosity.

Comment: Ints don't have leading zeros.

Comment: Decimals don't, but octals have the notation 0XX... where the x's are digits. Octals can be entered in the integer field, so I was wondering if error checking could be built for this issue.

Comment: Don't confuse notation with value.

Comment: Could you explain how I am confusing them? 0123 is a valid input in the integer field and has a different value from 123. I am asking if it could be determined which one was entered and have the function return null if it is an octal as opposed to finding the binary equivalent of 0123 (equal to decimal 83).

Comment: What do you mean by "the integer field"?

Comment: By integer field, I meant the parameter the method takes, the value of which is represented by "decimal". So if you call the method from somewhere and enter decimalToBinary(0123), I want it to return null as opposed to the same result as decimalToBinary(83).

Comment: I noticed my original post was downvoted. Was it because it was not clear enough from the start? Wanted to know for future question writing.

Comment: I would implement or use library methods, even maybe java standard library, for any normal number type and just convert between those. So the value is stored as int and exposed to your programm as ".asDecimal()" or ".asOctal()" or with the java library "Integer.toString(i, radix)"

It really depends on your usecase. Currently your implementation isn't guranteed to be right ever. You can only reject a subset of decimal numbers from the octal method and only guess whether a number entered into the octal method is actually already octal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

0123 is a way of writing the number "eighty three" in Java.

If you wanted "one hundred and twenty three" then you have to write 123 (or 0173 or 0x7b).

You are telling your method to convert eighty three to binary, and it is doing so. There is no problem with your method.

Comment: Thank you so much this makes perfect sense! I thought there was some fancy string conversion that could be done before java sees it as 83, but I guess that is not the case.